# fsck error on boot: dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv: UNEXPECTED INCONSISTENCY; RUN fsck MANUALLY

Tags: filesystems, boot, fsck

I try to boot into Ubuntu I get this message:

```
Begin: Will now check root file system ... fsck from util-linux 2.37.2
[/usr/sbin/fsck.ext4 (1) -- dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv] fsck.ext4 -a -C0 /dev

dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv: the filesystem size (according to the superblock)
the physical size of the device is 39321600 blocks
either the superblock ot the partition table is likely to be corrupt!

dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv: UNEXPECTED INCONSISTENCY; RUN fsck MANUALLY.
        (i.e., without -a or -p options)
fsck exited with status code 4
The root filesystem on dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv requires a manual fsck

Busybox v1.30.1 (Ubuntu 1:1.30.1-7ubuntu3) built in shell (ash)
Enter 'help' for a list of built-in commands.
```

How can I fix this?

is it possible to to fix that, and didnt lost my data